# Is it possible to use JOLT to transform this HTML to a JSON response

Tags: html, json, jolt

I would like to know if it is possible to use JOLT SPEC to transform this HTML to JSON:

```
[<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY><br>
#Message Receive correctly<br>
ORDERID=1725786449<br>
</BODY>
</HTML>]
```

**Expected:**

{
"MessageID":"1725786449"
}

Comment: No, Jolt transformation can be applied only to the JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible as Jolt is JSON to JSON transformation engine

Workaround could be.. converting the HTML to JSON first.
Basically using a XML to JSON conveter.(Html is a type of XML)

Then doing the required transformation for the required output.

Won't work with the above HTML snippet as it has br tag.